# How to duplicate Rows with new entries

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a SQL table that have ID , start and End Dates.  Example,

```
ID   StartDt    EndDt
123  1/1/2010   12/31/2014 
456  7/16/2013  11/20/2014
```

Based on Oct-Sept FY calendar I can get the FY from the dates (e.g., 2010 and 2015 for ID 123). However, I would like to duplicate the row with the initial and last FY; and the in-between FY. Below is what I would like to have from the above rows of data:

ID FY

123 2010

123 2011

123 2012

123 2014

123 2015

456 2013

456 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below uses a recursive CTE to count years from the start date fiscal year to the end date fiscal year.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        ID,
        YEAR(StartDt) AS FY,
        YEAR(EndDt) AS EY
    FROM [Source]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        ID,
        FY + 1,
        EY
    FROM CTE
    WHERE FY < EY
)
    SELECT ID, FY FROM CTE ORDER BY ID, FY
```

Comment: Thank you. It was swift. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive `cte` to get a list of all possible years, then `JOIN` to that:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT 2010 AS Yr
              UNION ALL
              SELECT Yr + 1
              FROM cte
              WHERE Yr < 2015)
SELECT a.ID, b.Yr
FROM YourTable a
JOIN cte b
  ON b.Yr BETWEEN YEAR(a.StartDt) AND YEAR(a.EndDt)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a list of numbers.  A convenient way is `master..spt_values`:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) - 1 as n
      from master..spt_values
     )
select id, year(t.startDt) + n.n as fy
from table t join
     n
     on dateadd(year, n.n, t.startDt) <= t.endDt;
```